# Extract connected pixels in a binary image using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, recursion, crash

I have a binary image - black pixels (0) and white (1).
I want to write a function that takes the image,and location of a black pixel - x and y and returns the locations of all the pixels that are connected (connected=8-connected) with the given pixel, and a total count of all the connected pixels.
for example if this is my image:

```
1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1
```

and I give the function pixel (1,1) the output will be:

```
count=3
x=[1,2,2]
y=[1,1,2]
```

here is what I did:

```
def find_connectivity(img,i,j,count,x,y):
    sys.setrecursionlimit(50000)
    if(img[i][j]==0):
        img[i][j]=2

        count=count+1
        xx=x
        yy=y
        xx=xx.append(i)
        yy=yy.append(j)
    rows=[-1, 0 ,1]
    cols=[-1, 0 ,1]
    for r in rows:
        for c in cols:
            if(img[i+r][j+c]==0):
                count,x,y= find_connectivity(img,i+r,j+c,count,x,y)
    return count,x,y
```

when I initial count to 0, and x and y to [].
for example in the previous example the call to the function would be:

```
[count,x,y]=find_connectivity(img,1,1,0,[],[])
```

now, this function works for fairly big groups (5300+) - but for more than that, I get a message "python.exe has stop working". 
with the following error details:

```
Application Timestamp:  5665e7c3
Fault Module Name:  ntdll.dll
Fault Module Version:   6.1.7601.19045
Fault Module Timestamp: 56259295
Exception Code: c00000fd
Exception Offset:   00000000000510a1
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   2a7e
Additional Information 2:   2a7edff1635197ae43266443b8d73ae8
Additional Information 3:   6edf
Additional Information 4:   6edf0945fe78222ec4c56cecff238926
```

I guess its because of the recursion - but I can't think of another efficient way of doing that.

Is there a function in openCV/numpy/other that can help me?
Or is there a way to prevent the crash, with the recursion?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, is `2` signifying the fact that you've visited the node? I advise you to try Breadth-First-Search if you know how to do it, it will run much swifter.

Comment: why not using OpenCV [connectedComponents](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#connectedcomponents) or [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours)? There's no need to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) like the following

```
import queue
def find_connectivity(img, i, j):
    dx = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1]
    dy = [1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1]
    x = []
    y = []
    q = queue.Queue()
    if img[i][j] == 0:
        q.put((i, j))
    while q.empty() == False:
        u, v = q.get()
        x.append(u)
        y.append(v)
        for k in range(8):
            xx = u + dx[k]
            yy = v + dy[k]
            if img[xx][yy] == 0:
                img[xx][yy] = 2
                q.put((xx, yy))
    return x, y
```

Comment: Your solution is almost perfect, you just have to remember to change the value of img[i][j] each time it equals to 0 - otherwise the while loop will be infinite. 
Thanks so much anyway!

Comment: Sorry I forget it. I have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not interested in the contour you can simply use a seeded flood fill algorithm. Also see region growing, region filling

Use your point as the seed point and fill the region with some value other than 0 or 1. Count pixels with that new value or list them to get number and their coordinates.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html
See floodFill.